# Matlab - Storing information in vectors and modelling a system of equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I'm working on solving a system of differential equations and I'm having trouble setting up a vector of parameters.
This is the code for one of my model files:
function dy1dt=LogisticsModel(t,y1,param1)
r1=param1(1);
k1=param1(2);
dy1dt=r1*y1*(1-(y1/k1));
This is the code for the other:
function dy2dt=LogisticsModel2(t,y2,param2)
r2=param2(1);
k2=param2(2);
dy2dt=r2*y2*(1-(y2/k2));
Basically, I just want a vector, param, containing r1, k1, r2, k2.  Whenever I try to set it up like 
r1=param(1);
k1=param(2);
r2=param(3);
k2=param(4);
I get error messages.  I've tried several different methods to do this and I can't figure it out.  Please help.

Comment: What exactly are your errors? That should work just fine in principle.

Comment: It doesn't really say - I don't know, when I run it it doesn't work but when I changed it to param1 and param2 it did.

Comment: What are you running with it? Are you using some other function, or just calling these?

Comment: These are codes from my model files.  The m file code that I call it with is: r2=.75;
k2=200;
param2=[r2,k2];
[t,y2]=ode45(@LogisticsModel2,[0,25],2,[],param2);

Comment: Your problem is in ode45: the first argument of ode45 must be a function of exactly two variables. (Of course the "y" variable can be a vector, but you get the idea.) What you should do is define an inline function which calls LogisticsModel2 with your param2 vector, something like f=@(t,y) LogisticsModel2(t,y,param2), then call ode45 with f. Sometimes CS people call this a "closure".